# How to order checked checkbox at the top of the list in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am consuming data from **api** and display it in the normal list view along with checkbox.There are two api where I have full list of resource in one and selected resource in another.

**Currently like this**

[image]

**Expected list would be**

[image]

**here is my checkbox in ng-repeat loop**

```
<div class="search" ng-repeat="resource in ViewData.resources">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{resource.resourceName}}" ng-model="resourceList[resource.resourceId]" 
                            ng-click="resourceChange(resource.resourceId)"
                            ng-checked="checkSelectedResource(resource.resourceId)"> 
    <label class="list{{resource.resourceId}}" >{{resource.resourceName}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `checkSelectedResource(resource.resourceId)` returns what, true or false?

Comment: i would do that by a filter -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter if it needs to be updated when checked. Or if you are fine sorting it once and not updating than maybe inside the promise from the http call?

Comment: @Pankaj its return `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/fqdqbpbc/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="search" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | orderBy:['-checked','name']:false">
    <input id="fruit{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.checked"> 
      <label for="fruit{{$index}}">{{fruit.name}}</label>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <p>fruits model:</p>
   <pre>{{fruits|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [
      {name:'apple',checked:false},
      {name:'banana',checked:false},
      {name:'orange',checked:false}
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. But this approach wasn't worked for my scenario.

Comment: @SenthilSivaramakrishnan it's just an example. I don't know how your ViewData.resources look like or resourceChange() etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can control with `ng-if`. if `ng-checked` items are true, you can use `ng-show="$first"`

Comment: it would help me if you could share any example code since I am new into this approach. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
<div class="search" ng-repeat="resource in ViewData.resources">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{resource.resourceName}}" ng-model="resourceList[resource.resourceId]" 
                            ng-click="resourceChange(resource.resourceId)"
                            ng-checked="$first"> 
    <label class="list{{resource.resourceId}}" >{{resource.resourceName}}</label>
</div>
```

you can easily trigger click event of first element in Controller like

```
   $scope.checkFirst=function(first){if(first == true){ //your function }}
```

and if you want to order for instance by name do this

```
 ng-repeat="resource in ViewData.resources | orderBy://name for example
```